# Value is not getting filled for <ng-otp-input> through formControlName

Tags: angular, form-control, ng-otp-input

I have used ng-otp-input in my code with formcontrolname but Value is not getting fetched. It is getting filled for other formcontrolname in the sameformgroup. Is there anything else I need to do for  type of input?

```html
<form [formGroup]="usernameForm" >
    <label class="form-labels">Mobile Number (Username)</label>                       
    <mat-form-field class="form-fields">                  
        <input formControlName="mobileno"  type="number" matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
                      
    <div class="hint-text">The Mobile number should belong to you and can be used only once to create a account and username.</div>  
    <div *ngIf="generateOtpFlag">
        <label class="form-labels">Mobile OTP</label> 
        <ng-otp-input formControlName="mobileotp" [config]="config"></ng-otp-input>
        <div class="timer-class">
            <div *ngIf="timer > 0">
                Resend OTP in 00 : {{timer}}
            </div>
            <div class="resendOTP" (click)="generateOtp()" *ngIf="timer <= 0">
                Resend OTP
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg generateOtp-btn" (click)='generateOtpFlag ? verifyMobile() : generateOtp()'>{{generateOtpFlag ? 'Verify & Continue': 'Generate OTP'}}</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

From their source code and documentation, we can see that they don't implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface, which is the interface that allows Angular Forms to use the `FormControl` class. Instead, they have their own mechanism, on which you supply the `FormControl` through an input.

Bellow there is an example taken from their documentation.

`<ng-otp-input  [formCtrl]="YourFormControl"  [config]="{length:5}"></ng-otp-input>`

Comment: yeah tried using this, still not working.  Neither the ngModel is working. For otp input data is not binding.

Comment: Can you show how have you tried to use it? Show the TypeScript code as well as the HTML.